# Join list2 for every string in list1

Tags: python, string, list, join, output

I have two lists already set up like this

```
List1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
List2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

I want to join every string of list2 for every string in list1, for example, I would want the final result of the above lists to look like this in a text file:

```
A:1
A:2
A:3
A:4
A:5
B:1
B:2
B:3
B:4
B:5
C:1
C:2
C:3
C:4
C:5
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you want the Cartesian `product` of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this would help...

```
List1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
List2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
file1 = open("MyFile.txt","w") 
for i in List1:
    for j in List2:
        file1.write(i+":"+j+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `product` function from the `itertools` library:

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
with open("text_file.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for element_from_list1, element_from_list2 in product(list1, list2):
        text_file.write((element_from_list1 + ":" + element_from_list2 + "\n"))
```

Will result in

`A:1
A:2
A:3
A:4
A:5
B:1
B:2
B:3
B:4
B:5
C:1
C:2
C:3
C:4
C:5`

in the text file